# Delete View when dragged to another View in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swiftui

I have an array of Views in a parent View in SwiftUI. Each of those Views in the array have a drag gesture that allows me to move them individually across the screen.

I also have another View in my parent View, resembling a trashcan icon.

When I drag one of my array Views into the space of the trashcan View, how can I remove that dragged View from the array so that it is effectively 'deleted' from the screen?

This is the same question asked here, but I'm looking for a SwiftUI solution instead of obj-c: [Removing a UILabel when dragged to an image](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17765792/12533955)

Edit: This is what the code looks like

Parent View:

```
struct parentView: View {

    @State var childViews: [ChildView]

    var body: some View {

        ForEach(self.childViews, id: \.childId) { childView in
            childView
        }
        .overlay(
            DeleteIcon()
                .padding(.top, 200)
        )

    }
}
```

Child View (there are several of these):

```
struct ChildView: View {

    let childId = UUID()

    // dragging vars
    @State private var currentPosition: CGSize = .zero
    @State private var newPosition: CGSize = .zero

    var dragGesture: some Gesture {
        DragGesture()
            .onChanged { value in
                self.currentPosition = CGSize(width: value.translation.width + self.newPosition.width, height: value.translation.height + self.newPosition.height)
            }
            .onEnded { value in
                self.currentPosition = CGSize(width: value.translation.width + self.newPosition.width, height: value.translation.height + self.newPosition.height)
                self.newPosition = self.currentPosition
            }
    }


    var body: some View {
        Rectangle()
            .fill(Color.blue)
            .frame(width: 200, height: 200)
            .offset(x: currentPosition.width, y: currentPosition.height)
            .gesture(dragGesture)

    }
}
```

Delete icon:

```
struct DeleteIcon: View {
    var body: some View {
        Rectangle()
            .fill(Color.red)
            .frame(width: 50, height: 200)
    }
}
```

Comment: Would you provide your code?

Comment: @Asperi code has been added for clarity

Answer (score 1):

I've made a very simple and crude test, where dragging to the left edge of the screen 
will "delete" the circle. To "delete" from the screen I used the "showMe" var and an EmptyView. In essence I'm just replacing the view with an empty one.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
var body: some View {
    Group {
        DragThing(pos: CGPoint(x:111,y:111), name: "test1")
        DragThing(pos: CGPoint(x:133,y:133), name: "test2")
        DragThing(pos: CGPoint(x:166,y:166), name: "test3")
    }
}
}

struct DragThing: View {

@State private var pos = CGPoint.zero
@State private var name = ""
@State private var showMe = true

init(pos: CGPoint, name: String) {
    _pos = State(initialValue: pos)
    _name = State(initialValue: name)
}

var body: some View {
    showMe ?
        AnyView(ZStack {
            Circle().foregroundColor(.blue).frame(width: 100, height: 100)
            Text(self.name).foregroundColor(.white)
        }.position(self.pos).highPriorityGesture(self.drag))
        : AnyView(EmptyView())
}

var drag: some Gesture {
    DragGesture().onChanged { value in
        self.pos = CGPoint(x: value.location.x, y: value.location.y)
        if self.pos.x < 40 {
            self.showMe = false
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Is there any way to get the coordinate location of a View? So that when the location.x and location.y coordinates of the draggable View are 'inside' the other View's coordinates, the draggable View can be deleted? That would be the solution I'm after

Comment: yes, for that you need to use GeometryReader with  the appropriate coordinateSpace modifier.